# Django static file on false debug runing on IIS

Tags: django, iis

I started a django site on my VPS and it works perfectly when the debug is True but when I change it to False it don't show the static file. 
I searched a lot and I know that "With debug turned off Django won't handle static files for me any more"  and my web server should handle it but how should I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install nginx and gunicorn.

I followed this [link](http://tutos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/ndg.html) for setting up the server for nginx, gunicorn and django combo.

create the django application server using gunicorn. point the sock file and static files to nginx. There is a clear step by step procedure etched out in the link. Please let me know if you have any queries beyond this point.